# Frequentist vs Bayesian approach

Tags: probability

There are 2 players - Alice and Bob. They don't see a pool table. Caroll rolls the ball on the table and marks the place where ball stops. Then she begins to roll new balls on the table: if the ball stops left to initial mark, Alice gets 1 points, right to initial mark - Bob gets 1 point. After 8 rounds Alice has 5 points and Bob has 3 points. Every round one of 2 players gets 1 point and the winner of the game is the one who gets 6 points first.

What is expected probability of Alice winning the game considering:

Frequenstist approach
Bayes approach
I calculated probability by summing up probabilities of Alice wins at least once in 3 rounds:

W = 5/8
LW = 3/8*5/8
LLW = 3/8 * 3/8 * 5/8

The total sum is 94.7%

Would it be correct considering this variant as frequentist approach? How to calculate probability using Bayes approach?

Comment: Clarification requested: "They don't see a pool table".  What do you mean by this?

Comment: That's what is said in the problem. I guess the idea is that Alice and Bob do not influence on their results.

Comment: I'm thinking the OP means no one sees the pool table when they roll the balls, to ensure that the results of the rolls are random. however, i agree with you that the post is unclear

Comment: @Anatoli did you find any of the posts below helpful?

Comment: Yes, thank you! A accepted one of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distinction between frequentist and Bayesian has less to do with the actual *computation* of probabilities and more to do with the *interpretation* of probabilities. A frequentist interprets the probability of an event as the long run, relative frequency with which an event occurs; a Bayesianist interprets the probability of an event as a level of belief that a particular event occurs. As it turns out, the mathematics in both approaches are the same due to the fact that "long run, relative frequencies" and "levels of belief" obey the same axioms. But the Bayesian framework is arguably more useful because it offers a mathematical approach for updating one's subjective beliefs in light of new information, even if those beliefs were inaccurate to begin with. This update is performed via Bayes Theorem, which states

$$ P(H|E) = \frac {P(H)P(E|H)} {P(E)} $$

where $H$ is an event corresponding to some hypothesis, and $E$ is an event corresponding to some evidence, or new information. Here, $P(H)$, known as the *prior*, is the level of belief one has in the hypothesis in the absence of new information; $P(H|E)$, known as the *posterior*, is the level of belief one has in the hypothesis when accounting for the new information; $P(E|H)$, known as the *likelihood*, is the probability of observing the new information given the hypothesis is true (in this case the probability is usually calculated as a long run, relative frequency); and $P(E)$, known as the *normalization constant*, is the probability of observing the evidence over all available hypotheses (again, in this case the probability is usually calculated as a long run, relative frequency).

One criticism of the Bayesian approach is that the level of belief assigned to the prior is often subjective, inevitably leading to a subjective level of belief for the posterior as well. In cases where the prior can be rigorously computed, this criticism becomes increasingly moot, especially if the prior is computed as a long run, relative frequency. In cases where it cannot be rigorously computed, it is worth noting the following: for one, even if the prior is "inaccurate," the posterior nonetheless represents a sound transition of one's belief to a "more accurate" level. Secondly, even if the prior is "inaccurate," in the limit the posterior will converge on the same probabilities that a frequentist would compute if Baye's Theorem is applied recursively with more and more new evidence. It's also worth noting that the Bayesian approach is indistinguishable from the frequentist approach whenever levels of belief are computed as long run, relative frequencies. In other words, frequentism *falls out* of Bayesianism whenever long run, relative frequencies are exclusively used.

Let events $H, E$ be defined as follows:

$
\begin{array}{ll}
H: & \text{the event in which Alice wins the game} \\
E: & \text{the event in which Alice has $5$ points and Bob has $3$ points after eight rounds} \\
\end{array}
$

Hereafter, I define the probabilities $P(H),P(E),P(E|H),$ and $P(H|E)$ as follows:

$
\begin{array}{ll}
P(H): & \text{the probabilitiy (or level of belief) of Alice winning} \\
& \text{the game without knowledge that Alice and Bob have $5$ and $3$ points,} \\ 
& \text{respectively, after eight rounds.} \\
\end{array}
$

At the beginning of the game, before a single round is played, we may have an initial level of belief that Alice will win, which we define as $P(H)$. The level of belief assigned to $P(H)$ can be whatever we like, but it is desirable to set our level of belief to the long run, relative frequency of $H$, and since this is feasible to compute, there is no good reason *not* to. So, we proceed as follows... in the absence of any knowledge about how the game unfolds, we have no reason to believe the initial mark on the table would favor Alice any more than Bob. Assuming $0<p<1$ is the probability that Alice gets a point on any given round, due to the position of the initial mark, then $p$ is a continuous, uniform random variable with pdf $f(p) = \frac{1}{1-0} = 1$ and expectation $E[p] = \frac{1+0}{2} = 0.5$, implying Alice and Bob would be expected to win the game with equal probability, so $P(H) = 0.5$. For a more detailed examination, consider Alice can win in no less than $6$ and no more than $11$ rounds. For a fixed $p$, the probability she wins in exactly $n$ rounds is given by ${n-1 \choose 5} p^6 (1-p)^{n-6} $. Hence, for a fixed $p$, the probability she wins the game is given by $\sum_{n=6}^{11} {n-1 \choose 5} p^6 (1-p)^{n-6}$. Finally, since $p$ is a random variable, the probability Alice wins the game is itself a random variable $X$ with expectation

$$ P(H) = E[X] = \int_0^1 \sum_{n=6}^{11} {n-1 \choose 5} p^6 (1-p)^{n-6} f(p) dp = 0.5 $$

$
\begin{array}{ll}
P(E): & \text{the probability that Alice has $5$ points and Bob has $3$ points} \\
& \text{after eight rounds.} \\
\end{array}
$

Now, after eight rounds of play, we observe the point total and would like to update our level of belief in the proposition that Alice wins the game. But first we must compute the probability of observing this newly acquired evidence independent of who wins the game. For a fixed $p$, the probabilty that Alice has $5$ points and Bob has $3$ points after eight rounds is given by the mass function of a binomial random variable $X$~$B(8,5)$, that is, ${8 \choose 5} p^5 (1-p)^3$. However, since $p$ is a continuous, uniform random variable, this mass function is itself a random variable $Y$ with expectation

$$ P(E) = E[Y] = \int_0^1 {8 \choose 5} p^5 (1-p)^3 f(p) dp $$

$$ = 56 \int_0^1 p^5 - 3p^6 +3p^7 - p^8 dp = 56 \Big( \frac{1}{6} - \frac{3}{7} + \frac{3}{8} - \frac{1}{9} \Big) = \frac{11}{99} \approx 0.1111$$

$
\begin{array}{ll}
P(E|H): & \text{the probabilitiy Alice has $5$ points and Bob has $3$ points after eight} \\
& \text{rounds } conditioned \text{ on the event that Alice wins the game.} \\
\end{array}
$

Now we must compute the probability of observing the newly acquired evidence assuming that Alice does in fact win the game. By definition of conditional probability, we have

$$ P(E|H) = \frac{P(E,H)}{P(H)} = \frac{P(E,H)}{0.5} $$

leaving us with the task of computing the joint probability $P(E,H)$. For a fixed $p$, the probability of Alice getting $5$ points in eight trials is ${8 \choose 5} p^5 (1-p)^3$, and the probability of her winning over the rest of the game is given by $1-(1-p)^3$. The two probabilities are independent, so the joint probability is ${8 \choose 5} p^5 (1-p)^3 (1-(1-p)^3)$ for a fixed $p$. However, since $p$ is a continuous, uniform random variable, this joint probability is itself a random variable $Z$ with expectation

$$ P(E,H) = E[Z] = \int_0^1 {8 \choose 5} p^5 (1-p)^3 (1-(1-p)^3) f(p) dp = \frac{10}{99} \approx 0.1010$$

and now we compute $P(E|H)$ as

$$ P(E|H) = \frac{P(E,H)}{P(H)} = \frac{0.1010}{0.5} = \frac{20}{99} \approx 0.2020$$

$
\begin{array}{ll}
P(H|E): & \text{the probabilitiy (or level of belief) that Alice wins the game} \\
& \text{given Alice has $5$ points and Bob has $3$ points after eight rounds.} \\
& \text{This is the answer to the problem you posed.} \\
\end{array}
$

Now we may use Baye's Theorem to compile the former results and compute the posterior.

$$ P(H|E) = \frac {P(H)P(E|H)} {P(E)} \approx \frac {0.5(0.2020)} {0.1111}  \approx 0.9090 $$

So, using Bayes Theorem we are able to update our belief that Alice wins the game from $0.5$ to $0.9090$ in light of the newly acquired evidence, that is, the point total after eight rounds of play. This would be the perspective of a Bayesianist.

From the perspective of a frequentist, we have shown that Alice is expected to win $0.5$ of all games that begin in round one with Alice and Bob having $0$ points. In addition, we have shown that Alice is expected to win $0.9090$ of all games that begin in round eight with with Alice and Bob having $5$ and $3$ points, respectively.

Comment: It's not clear to me that whether Alice wins or Bob wins is a $50$-$50$ proposition. In fact, I suspect the reason why the question is being asked is that it isn't.

Comment: that is a good point. i will have to update my response.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "frequentist" or "Bayesian" approach here; there is just a correct answer or an incorrect answer. To get the correct answer, we have to use conditional probability, but a frequentist statistician isn't going to refuse to use conditional probability, they will just interpret it differently.

Here's a way to simplify the problem: rather than stopping immediately after someone wins, let's say that we stop after $11$ points exactly, and the winner is whoever has more points at that point. (This is actually equivalent: at this point, the winner has at least $6$ points, and the loser does not.) At the end of the game, Carol has rolled a total of $12$ balls, including the initial ball that sets the mark. Assuming Carol doesn't cheat, the rolls are identical, which means that if we sort the $12$ balls by the distance they rolled, each permutation is equally likely.

Let $A_{n,k}$ be the event that after $n$ turns, Alice has exactly $k$ points. We are given that the event $A_{8,5}$ occurred. In order for Bob to win from here, we need Alice to stay at $5$ points until the end: $\Pr[\text{Bob wins} \mid A_{8,5}] = \Pr[A_{11,5} \mid A_{8,5}]$. By definition of conditional probability, $$\Pr[A_{11,5} \mid A_{8,5}] = \frac{\Pr[A_{11,5} \cap A_{8,5}]}{\Pr[A_{8,5}]}.$$
The probability $\Pr[A_{8,5}]$ is exactly $\frac19$. The first $9$ balls are equally likely to be in any permutation; in particular, the first ball (which sets the mark) could be in any position. Event $A_{8,5}$ is exactly the event that there are $5$ balls left of the first ball and $3$ balls right of the first ball, so the first ball must be in the $6^{\text{th}}$ position from the left. This has probability $\frac19$.

For the event $\Pr[A_{11,5} \cap A_{8,5}]$, let's count permutations. The left-to-right order needs to include $5$ of the balls rolled in the first $8$ rounds (in any order), then the initial ball, then the remaining $6$ balls (in any order). There are $\binom 85 \cdot 5! \cdot 6!$ such permutations, out of $12!$ total; therefore
$$
   \Pr[A_{11,5} \cap A_{8,5}] = \frac{\binom 85 \cdot 5! \cdot 6!}{12!} = \frac1{99}.
$$
Therefore $\Pr[A_{11,5} \mid A_{8,5}] = \frac{1/99}{1/9} = \frac1{11}$; given the outcome of the first $8$ rounds, Bob wins with probability $\frac1{11}$ and Alice wins with probability $\frac{10}{11}$.

The frequentist vs. Bayesian distinction lies in what this probability means.

- A Bayesian would say, "Given that we observe Alice having $5$ points after $8$ rounds, we should update our degree of belief that Alice will win to a probability of $\frac{10}{11}$."
- A frequentist would say, "If Alice and Bob play this game many times, then in the long run, out of all games where Alice had $5$ points after $8$ rounds, she would win $\frac{10}{11}$ of them."

Comment: "but a frequentist statistician isn't going to refuse to use conditional probability,": sadly they sometimes will indeed.  The unobserved position to which Carroll rolled the ball is easily cast as a random variable even in the frequentist conception, but there are other versions of this problem where it will be viewed as an "unknown parameter", and *illegitimate* to consider in distributions in different positions.  You can almost always "expand the sample space" to get around this, but sometimes its very very hard.

Comment: Yes, the frequentist and Bayesian approach will disagree in cases where some parameter cannot possibly be the subject of repeated experiments. (If we imagine the pool table as having an old scuff mark on it, which Carol uses as the cutoff, then suddenly the philosophical side of things becomes more complicated!) Nonetheless, I do not want to falsely claim that the frequentist approach objects to *every* use of conditional probability, and in particular I think it is fine here.

Comment: (Unrelatedly, the comment above made me notice that I've been typing "Caroll" as "Carol" the whole time, and now I wonder if "Caroll rolls the ball" was intended as a pun!)

Comment: If I change the formula Pr[A11,5∩A8,5] to P(A8,5/A11,5) * P (11,5) what should be my inputs? P (11,5) = 1/12; P(A8,5/A11,5) - ?

Comment: For $\Pr[A_{8,5}\mid A_{11,5}]$ we assume that at the end, 5 of 11 balls are left of the mark; we want the probability that all 5 of them come from the first 8 rounds. This probability is $\binom85/\binom{11}5 = \frac4{33}$.